# I am having trouble finding $f'(x)$ given $f(x) = \frac{4}{x}$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I am having trouble finding $f'(x)$ given $f(x) = \frac{4}{x}$. I used the definition of a derivative but I got stuck. I think the right answer is $\frac{-4}{x^2}$ but I am stuck at $\frac{-4h}{x(x+h)}$. My work is posted down below. Thank you.[image]

Comment: You missed a $h$ in the denominator while splitting. Then $x+h\approx x$ should give you the result

Comment: You keep writing $f'(x)=\frac{4}{x}$. But $f'(x)$ is not $\frac{4}{x}$. So don't say they're equal!

Comment: Please try to learn mathjax from [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) designed for beginners and type your effort using mathjax. It's not difficult and the mathjax fonts look so damn beautiful!!

Comment: Also write "I am having trouble finding $f'(x) $ given $f(x) =4/x$".

Comment: @DatBoi20 Wow no wonder people say Calculus is not hard and the reason why people fail Calculus is because of their algebra. Thank you.

Comment: @runway44 Yes thank you for letting me know. That was a typo.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What part of my post did I not use mathjax right? This is my first post using mathjax and yes I agree it looks better. Also, thanks for letting me know how to write the question a better way.

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac 4x$ then $f'(x)=\frac{-4}{x^2}$.

Comment: Indeed :) enjoy calculus!

Comment: There is no issues with the mathjax you have written. It's just that you wrote the wrong equation $f'(x) =4/x$. You perhaps wanted to write "find $f'(x) $ if $f(x) =4/x$".

Comment: @DatBoi Thank you!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Great thank you for the correction!

Comment: One more question. Is it okay to use $h$ instead of $\Delta$x when solving using the definition of a derivative? Is it the same thing?

Comment: Both $h$ and $\delta x$ are acceptable, there is no difference between them.

Comment: @player3236 Great that is good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting an answer for completeness's sake!

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{4}x$, then
$$\begin{align} 
f'(x) &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{4}{x+h} - \frac{4}{x}}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-4h}{hx(x+h)}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-4}{x(x+h)}\\&= \frac{-4}{x^2}
\end{align}$$